# How to use my created token, a coin, on my created smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I´m want to create a cryptcoin, and index its value to the value of a company.

So If the user contribute with my service, he will be rewarded with my coin. First, this coin wont have any value, but if the company grows, it gains value.

The part I did not understand, is How to use my created coin in the contracts I´ve made? I created a contract to pay rewards, and a coin token contract, using the samples. What´s the next steps?

Comment: You will have to start publiciting your project and how users will get rewards. Talk to the community, exchanges, potential investors. Then launch your token, if the potential investors believe your project is good they will invest and acquire your tokens. Exchanges will start trading your token if it is popular enough.

Comment: @Ismael it´s cool, but I just want to understand, if its possible to do what I sayd, create a coin, and use it on a smart contract that i did create.

Comment: There's a specification ERC20 at https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20 that standard tokens follows. Any contract is able to interact with tokens that follow such specification. OpenZeppelin have sample contracts that follow such spec.

Comment: Please correct me if I´m wrong but, If I create a token, and transfer founds from it to the contract hash, it will belong to the founds of the contract? Is it true?

Comment: If you create a contract, and you transfer funds to the contract address, this ethers will belong to the contract and no one else.

Comment: Is this case, how can I send this founds to another address, a third part address?

Comment: You can add to the contract a method to `send` the ethers to an account of your choice. My advice is to start from a sample token like the ones in OpenZeppelin github repo, they are used as base for tokens with public ICOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best advice I can give you is to start studying at the contracts created by the [OpenZeppelin project](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity). They provide several reviewed contracts that are used as base for projects with a public ICO. For more complex type of tokens you can take a look at [TokenMarketNet ICO repository](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico).

Also you should start with a framework like Truffle or Populus, that make creating, testing and deploying contracts much easier.

But you should try to keep up to date with current best practices, at any time a new vulnerability can appear. And the current best practices sometimes changes every month.