# How to create a token

Tags: blockchain, tokens

do you know how to create a token? If so can you please help me? I have some difficulties at the code.Thanks!

Comment: Question is very broad and there is a lot of content already on SE to help with this. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23591/how-to-create-a-token-smart-contract-that-sends-tokens-after-recieving-payment-i

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [Token Factory](http://tokenfactory.surge.sh/#/factory) to launch a token contract.

[image]

Token Factory is [open source](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Token-Factory).

Audited ERC20 token contracts can be found on [github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens) and [github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity).

Highly recommend to take a look at those first.

Related

- [How to create a token smart contract that sends tokens after recieving payment in ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23591/how-to-create-a-token-smart-contract-that-sends-tokens-after-recieving-payment-i)
- [How to use my created token, a coin, on my created smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17395/how-to-use-my-created-token-a-coin-on-my-created-smart-contract)
- [Is ERC20 Token Contracts the Only Way to Create Custom Tokens?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24526/is-erc20-token-contracts-the-only-way-to-create-custom-tokens)
- [Is it possible on Ethereum to create a token this way?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12099/is-it-possible-on-ethereum-to-create-a-token-this-way)

Comment: This Token Factory sucks. Without telling you, it takes into account the decimals when you specify the total supply eg 10 tokens with 4 decimal places should be 100000 - not 10!!!!. So the suggested placeholder values of 10 with 4 decimal places wouldn't work at all. Plus there is no implementation of selfDestruct - so you can't ever remove the contract from the blockchain! Arrrggghhh. Not good.

Comment: @jsdeveloper I agree that there should be info text that tells you you should take account decimal places. There's usually no good reason to self destruct however. All the code is open source so you can make modifications and run it your self https://github.com/ConsenSys/Token-Factory